# Why Does 'import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router;' Syntax Work?

Tags: angular

Basically, what the title says. Why can I just provide the `@angular/whatever` as a route instead of providing a legitimate route like I would for custom components? ( for example: `import {FooModule} from ../../somefolder/some-exported-es6-module` )

An example of this can be seen in the start-up app:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue

e.g.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
```

Does this only work with angular packages or is this some global syntax that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module loader is SystemJS which gets configured in config.ts to map "@angular/whatever" to some URL.

Comment: I am pretty sure this works with Webpack as well...but yea, I see it now. Thanks.